# Arduino infinite for loop

Tags: c++, arduino

I've been working an a projet on Arduino.
This is the code :

```
#include <ss.h>

//#include <Lampe.h>
//#include <Motor.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 


#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);  

}

void loop() {
  char* cc= "Bon{jour {ca{a v{a et{ toi?";
  Ss* str = new Ss(cc);
  Ss* tr;
  Serial.println(F("ON COMMENCE"));
  for(int k=0; k<20; k++){
    tr = str->substring(k);
    Serial.println(str->getString());
    Serial.println(tr->getString());
    Serial.println(k);
    Serial.println(F("--------------------------"));
  }
  delay(100000);

}
```

And the class Ss* :

```
#include "ss.h"
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <Arduino.h>

Ss::Ss(char* k){
    this->length = strlen(k);
  this->string = (char*) malloc(strlen(k));
    strcpy(this->string,k);
  this->string[length] = '\0';

}

int Ss::lengthh(){
  this->length = strlen(this->string);
  return this->length;
}

int Ss::getlength(){
  return this->length;
}

char* Ss::getString(){
  return this->string;
}

void Ss::setString(char* k){
  this->string = (char*) malloc (strlen(k));
  strcpy(this->string, k);
  this->lengthh();
  this->string[strlen(k)] = '\0';
}

char Ss::charAt(int n){
    return this->string[n];

}


Ss& Ss::operator=( const Ss& other ) {
      length = other.length;
      string = (char*) malloc(length);
      strcpy(string,other.string);
      string[length] = '\0';
      return *this;
  }




void Ss::concatt(char*& txt, char* txt2){
  int l1 = strlen(txt);
  int l2 = strlen(txt2);
  //Serial.println(txt);
  //Serial.println(txt2);
  const int ltot = l1+l2;
  char* txtconcat ;
  txtconcat = (char*) malloc(ltot);
  strcpy(txtconcat,txt);
  txtconcat[l1] = '\0';
  strcat(txtconcat,txt2);
  txtconcat[l1+l2] = '\0';
  txt = (char*) malloc(ltot);
  strcpy(txt,txtconcat);
  txt[l1+l2]= '\0';
  //Serial.println("On est dans concatt :   ");Serial.println(txt);
  free(txtconcat);

}




Ss* Ss::substring( int n){
      Ss* gauche = new Ss("");
      for(int k=0; k<n; k++){
        char* toadd = (char*) malloc(1);
        char c;
        c = this->charAt(k);
        char* cl = (char*) malloc(1);
        cl[0] = c;
        cl[1] = '\0';
        strcpy(toadd,cl);
        toadd[1] ='\0';
        char* tocopy = (char*) malloc(gauche->lengthh());
        strcpy(tocopy,gauche->getString());
        tocopy[gauche->getlength()] = '\0';
        concatt(tocopy,toadd);
        gauche->setString(tocopy);
        free(cl);
        free(toadd);
        free(tocopy);
      }
      gauche->string[gauche->lengthh()]= '\0';
      Serial.print(F("On est dans la fonction substring      ")); Serial.println(gauche->string);
      return gauche;
}




void Ss::remove(int pos, int nbchar){
  char* left = (char*) malloc(pos-1);
  char* right = (char*) malloc(this->lengthh()-pos-nbchar);
  left = strcpy(left,this->substring(pos)->string);
  right = strcpy(right,this->substringr(pos+nbchar)->string);
  left[strlen(left)] = '\0';
  right[strlen(right)] = '\0';
  Serial.println("###");
  Serial.println(right);
  Serial.println(strlen(right));
  Serial.println("###");
  concatt(left,right);free(right);
  strcpy(this->string,left);
  this->string[strlen(left)] = '\0';
  Serial.print("On est dans la fonction remove      "); Serial.println(this->string);
  free(left);

}
```

My issue is in the loop().
My for loop don't end, the delay is not taking into account. It seems like when the for loop reach 10, it resets the loop() function.

[This is what the BoardCom returne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mcXE.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it resets the loop() function'? what behaviour are you seeing and how is it different from what you expected?

Comment: Well, the counter does not go to 20 in the for loop, only to 10, and on the screenshot we can see that the line "ON COMMENCE" is printed over and over without taking into account the delay

Comment: What do you think should happen when you unnecessarily allocate memory on a device with limited memory, writing one more byte than you have allocated and not releasing the allocated memory. And all than in a loop?

Comment: Could you explain me where should I release my memory. I'm new on C++ and Arduino so I don't really understand where I should de-allocate my memory or where I should not allocate it !

Comment: You never release the memory allocated in `Ss` objects. Even if you do, it can still cause memory fragmentation.

Comment: It's highly advisable you don't use dynamic allocation in the Arduino environment. It's better you create your buffer manager! If your SW damages the MCU memory you may obtained a RESET or, in the worst case, a system hang of the MCU.

Answer (score 1):

When you develop code in the Arduino environment the code you write is compiled with a main.cpp that is into the core SW.

This code loops calling the function `loop()` that is in your code module.

Here the Arduino code:

```
/*
 * \brief Main entry point of Arduino application
 */
int main( void )
{
    init();

    initVariant();

    delay(1);

#if defined(USBCON)
    USBDevice.attach();
#endif

    setup();

    for (;;)
    {
        loop();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can see, in the main, that loop() is called forever!

Note that, in the main, the function `serialEventRun()` may be called when serial communication are enabled ( `if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();` ). If this behavior is avoided you will have no serial communication.

Comment: He never reaches the end of the loop function, because his Arduino is restarting.

Comment: Yes, I understood in a better way the question! :) ... I added a reply into the comment below the question! ... Excuse me!

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But what do you mean by using a buffer manager?

Comment: @Syndorik. I mean that is advisable you create a static array of memory and then use it to allocate/deallocate memory. This method is often used in MCU-programming. The delicate issue is that, if you use this technique, you have to write you memory manager. (I think is good exercise!)